# if $\max_{z \in K} |\zeta(z+it)-f(z)|<\epsilon.$ then is this $\lim_{t\to \infty} \inf \frac {|\zeta'(z+it)|}{|f'(z)|} $ a finit limit?

Tags: limits-and-convergence, riemann-zeta-function, approximation-theory, lower-bounds, universal-property

Universality theorem of Riemann zeta function states that :Let $K$ be a compact subset with connected complement lying in the strip $\{1/2 < \operatorname{Re}(z)<1\}$, and let $f : K \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be continuous, holomorphic on the interior of $K$, and zero-free on $K$. Then for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $t>0$ such that
$$\max_{z \in K} |\zeta(z+it)-f(z)|<\epsilon.$$ , which means the approximation of such holomorphic function by Riemann zeta function in the strip now my question here is : if we have $\max_{z \in K} |\zeta(z+it)-f(z)|<\epsilon.$ then  is this  $\lim_{t\to \infty} \inf \frac {|\zeta'(z+it)|}{|f'(z)|} $ a finit limit?

**Note:** The motivation of this question is to know more about growth rate of the ratio $\frac {\zeta'(z+it)|}{f'(z)} $

Comment: Is the infimum over $z\in K$? By the same universality theorem this infimum will oscilate between arbitrarily close to 0 and arbitrarily large arbitrarily often, so there is no limit.

Comment: Thanks for your comment , I have a wrong typo I meant limit of derivative ratio

Comment: $\zeta'$ is also universal (there should be a reference [here](https://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~kohjimat/Nicchuu13.pdf)) so the same holds.